# Server logged HTTP status code of 200, but Chrome HAR shows 403 - can the HTTP status code change?

Tags: django, http, nginx

I work on an application that uses Django / Gunicorn / Nginx / Amazon Elastic Load Balancer (ELB).

A user that only has access to Chrome has submitted two different [HAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) files that have recorded a 403 for a simple JSON API endpoint that hasn't been known to have issues for other users.

According to our logs from Nginx and Django middleware, those API requests returned 200 for that particular user.

### Primary Questions

1. **The network** - Practically speaking, is there any likely scenario which can cause an intermediary network to change a 200 to a 403 by the intermediary network? For example, is there any plausible scenario in which a MITM attack could cause a 200 to change into a 403, such as if the client's network has an [SSL Interceptor returning a 403](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-adc/current-release/forward-proxy/ssl-interception.html)?
2. **The browser** -  Is there anything in particular about HAR files or Chrome in general which could cause a browser to coerce a 403 from a 200? Is there anything which could cause the HAR record to differ from what would appear in the network tab?

### Secondary questions

1. **Nginx** - Is there anything that could cause Nginx to record a 200 when a 403 was returned?
2. **ELB** - Is there any situation in which ELBs can change the http status code when the ALB is in a relatively default configuration?

### Tertiary question

1. Have you ever seen a scenario like this before? If so, what was the end result?

Comment: Perhaps this might help you https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-403-issues Also primary, secondary, tertiary questions? Seems to be lacking focus...

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat - this is a useful link to ALB docs. We don't have WAF enabled on our ALB, so that's probably not it, though.

Comment: Another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58323263/intermittent-403-when-accessing-server-via-load-balancer-cant-figure-out-why , turns out the OP's firewall was doing that

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - thanks for this additional link - relevant to this discussion, but we don't have mod_security WAF enabled, and we're getting 200 in our nginx access logs instead of 403, so it's not likely the same issue.

Comment: You might have some other firewall though, mod_security is specific to that questions case.

Comment: The devops team and I can't think of any of our firewalls that could possibly impact this ajax request, which is working for all other users, and for this particular user in all other cases but one. Is it possible that a firewall in the user's network could change the the 200 to a 403? This is the part I'm fuzzy on.